# include php files from other servers in Laravel

Tags: laravel, include, server

I am working in a E-Commerce Laravel project. In this project, I need to include/require/import files stored in a different server of the E-Commerce. How I can do that? What are the paths I have to include? And what are the files I have to modify?

Answer (score 1):

You really do not want to do that. Even if there is a possibility to include php files from different machine, it's an awful idea. Do not do that.

If you need to get some data from another server, use RESTful API or something like this.